# after replace mapred/hdfs/common jar build via Hadoop from SVN "no namenode to stop"

Tags: hadoop

I checkout the source code from

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/hdfs

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/mapreduce

and get 
hadoop-mapred-0.23.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hadoop-hdfs -0.23.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
hadoop-common-0.23.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

but I failed to start-all.sh with these jars...

Jobtracker and tasktracker started for just 5 secs and automatically shut down...

Anyone could help?

I tried to check out the log

tasktracker said
2011-03-01 00:43:06,242 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO: Unable to initialize NativeIO libraries
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.initNative()V
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.initNative(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO.(NativeIO.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController.setup(TaskController.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.(TaskTracker.java:1391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3619)
2011-03-01 00:43:12,983 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9001 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy4.getProtocolSignature(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProtocolProxy(RPC.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProtocolProxy(RPC.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProtocolProxy(RPC.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$2.run(TaskTracker.java:710)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:706)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.(TaskTracker.java:1391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:251)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:224)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:132)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$PingInputStream.read(Client.java:368)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:698)

2011-03-01 00:43:12,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at Vaio-sz65/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to deal with it...
upgrade the dfs first!